# Is there a shorter / simpler query than this one?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this very simple models: a `Clip` can have many `AdBase` and an `AdBase` can have many `Clip`'s.

```
class AdBase(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, null=True,
                             blank=False)

class Clip(models.Model):
    ads = models.ManyToManyField(AdBase, related_name='clips',
                                 through='ClipAd')


class ClipAd(models.Model):
    clip = models.ForeignKey(Clip, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             blank=False, null=False)
    ad = models.ForeignKey(AdBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                           blank=False, null=False)
    position = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
```

I want in the class `Clip`, a query which returns all its clips ordered by their `position`.

I've come up with this:

```
class Clip(models.Model):
    ads = models.ManyToManyField(AdBase, related_name='clips',
                                 through='ClipAd')
    def ads_by_position(self):
        # there might be a simpler query than this:
        return [a.ad
                for a in ClipAd.objects.filter(clip=self).order_by('position')]
```

But I'm sure there's a simpler syntax using the `ads` property of my class `Clip` but I didn't find one.

Any idea (or is this the only solution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for this purpose. It will also decrease your DB load a lot. Also, using custom [managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/) worths a look.

```
class ClipManager(models.Manager):
    def get_with_adds():
        return Clip.objects.filter().prefetch_related("ads")


class AdBase(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")

class Clip(models.Model):
    ads = models.ManyToManyField(AdBase, related_name='clips',
                                 through='ClipAd')
    objects = ClipManager()


class ClipAd(models.Model):
    clip = models.ForeignKey(Clip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ad = models.ForeignKey(AdBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.IntegerField(default=0)

clips_with_adds = Clip.objects.get_with_adds()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access related many to many items directly:

```
def ads_by_position(self):
    return self.ads.all().order_by('position')
```

Comment: `FieldError at /blablah/
Cannot resolve keyword 'position' into field` because it tries to access to `AdBase` properties (here `title`)